# Different Behavior of Span on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a tooltip feature that when user hover to a span, the extra information will show up. However, when the span is split on 2 different lines, the extra information appears at 2 different positions on Firefox and Chrome.

[Firefox vs Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39R2u.png)

The left image is on Firefox, and the right side is Chrome. I'd prefer the behavior on Firefox because the extra information is closer to the original span. So how can I fix it specifically for Chrome? Thank you so much.

My code currently:

```css
    .current-span {
        position: relative;
    }

    .current-span:hover .extra-information {
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .extra-information {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: max-content;
        background-color: var(--color-fg);
        color: var(--color-bg);
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 3px;

        /* Position the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 110%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<span class="current-span">
  <span class="extra-information">rs1</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <br>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: can you please include also the html and possibly using a live snippet?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put a runnable snippet into your question. and include any code that alters the tooltip visibility.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my post. Here is also another Codepen link: https://codepen.io/alphaQHH/pen/ZEMjEoP

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the display property for span might not be the same in different browsers. I usually explicitly set it.
This will do:

```
.current-span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I should have named `current-span` to be clearer. I have many adjacent `current-span`, so I don't want it takes the whole width by using `block`.

Comment: In that case you can use float on `current-span`s as well. If that also didn't work use flex for the container.

Comment: btw, you can also try `inline-block` instead of `block`. Try this before using float.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you experience different behaviour has nothing to do with `<span>`. It's how Firefox and Chrome outline text.

Firefox outlines text "smarter" just like you noticed. However, it is not possible to make Chrome replicate the same behaviour easily.